# Show that the wave can be written in this form?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, complex-numbers

[image]

I have completed the first part of the question but left it in for context, however I am not entirely sure what the second part is asking, am I supposed to write the components added or multiplied such as:
$$f_{0}\exp\{i[(k_{0}\pm\delta k)x-(\omega_{0}\pm\delta\omega)t]\} + f_{0}\exp\{i[(k_{0}\pm\delta k)x-(\omega_{0}\pm\delta\omega)t]\}$$
and in this case if I rewrite them in the form $\exp(ix)=\cos(x) + i\sin(x)$ then maybe use small angle   approximations for $\delta k$ and $\delta\omega$? And also I'm not sure about what to do with the $\pm$ terms.

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to type out screenshots or images of text; for formulae, one can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $\psi(x, t)$ as a sum of the two solutions of the form $f_0 e^{i(k_0 +\delta k) x - i(\omega_0 + \delta \omega)t}$ and $f_0 e^{i(k_0 -\delta k) x - i(\omega_0 - \delta \omega)t}$ (since the two waves are assumed to have equal magnitude). Factoring out $e^{ik_0x - i\omega_0 t}$, we have

$$ \psi(x, t) = f_0 \left[ e^{i(k_0 +\delta k) x - i(\omega_0 + \delta \omega)t} + e^{i(k_0 -\delta k) x - i(\omega_0 - \delta \omega)t} \right]   $$
$$ = f_0 e^{ik_0 x - i\omega_0 t} \left[ e^{i\delta k x - i\delta \omega t}  + e^{-i\delta k x + i\delta \omega t}\right] . $$

Now, use the fact that $\cos(x) = \frac{1}{2} (e^{ix} + e^{-ix})$ and let $f_1 = 2f_0$ to obtain the desired expression.

Comment: Thanks that seems a lot easier than I was making it.